# Which Deep Learning model should I use to classify a multi-class problem with multi-label

Tags: algorithm, deep-learning, model, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I want to develop a deep learning model to classify some comments and reviews. Here is a little description of the data structure:

Each comment **could be related to one or more than one class** such as comments about phone battery, or phone's OS, or other classes (type analysis).

Each comment (such as a comment about phone battery and its OS) **could be positive or negative or neutral, just one of them** (sentiment analysis).

Now the question is that, should I develop multi models (one model per each class) that the model has 3 sentiment outputs, like below:

`DATA ==> TYPE DETECTION MODEL ==> output_1 (type of review)`

`DATA ==> SENTIMENT DETECTION MODEL ==> output_2 (sentiment of review)`

`REAL OUTPUT ==> output_1 + output_2`

Or should I develop one class that classify data through all possibilities (all types * all sentiments), like below:

`DATA ==> DETECT TYPE AND SENTIMENT MODEL ==> REAL OUTPUT`

Which one is the better way, or if there is another way that I don't know, I would appreciate it if you tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a sentiment analysis model and a binary classification model per topic.

I wouldn't combine the topic classification with the sentiment analysis. These are two separate tasks, and each deserves its own model.

As for the topic classification itself, I incline toward separate model per class, for two reasons:

First, this way we can get the full range of activations per class. If, for example, a text matches very well both class A and class B, we can expect the two corresponding models to indicate this, while if we used a single model, it's probable that only one of these classes will stand out.

Second, a model constructed with separate classifiers is more extendible. Adding another topic amounts to training a new classifier on that topic. If we go with one big classifier, adding a topic requires retraining the model on all topics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I agree with your reasons. But imagine a situation that you developed a tool that predicts topics and the sentiment of comments. Let's say we have 8 topics (which means that we have 8 binary classification models per each topic) and a sentiment analysis model (overall 9 models). So, when a comment is received, it should pass from all the models to find the real output, and that causes a big run time. But I got your idea, it's better to separate them, for example, 3 models (4 topics per each model and one sentiment analysis model)

Comment: If performance is important, the processing of a new text by the models can be made parallel.

Comment: Sounds logical. Thank you for your tips